# MySQL DATE_FORMAT '%M' for short month?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display dates like this `27-Jul-13`. I keep reading that `M` should give the shorthand month and `F` the full name. I am using this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%M-%y') AS Displaydate
```

but it displays like this: `14-April-12` not `14-Apr-12`

Also if I use `F` it doesn't work at all, it just displays an `F` where the month should be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%M-%y') AS Displaydate` is probably `mysql`, not `php`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) doc, you need `%b` for your format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%b-%y') AS Displaydate
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%b-%y') AS Displaydate
```