# how to convert dd-mm-yyyy into DD-MON-yyyy in sql

Tags: sql

how to convert **dd-mm-yyyy** into **DD-MON-yyyy** in sql

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Specify if you want a select or update.  (3) Tag with the database that you are using.  You are new to the site, but this is simply not a viable question.

Comment: i want to convert 02-11-1992 into 02-Nov-1992

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL DATE\_FORMAT '%M' for short month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900458/mysql-date-format-m-for-short-month)

Comment: Date_Format is not recognized built in function name is SQL Server

Comment: which database are you using ? I mean MYSQL,Oracle or any other?
`select date_format(columnname ,'%d-%b-%Y') as format_date  from tableName` will work for MYSQL.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2012 SSMS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL DateTime Format Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053044/sql-datetime-format-convert)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-25'), 106);`

Comment: what error you are getting? can you show that. And also what datatype you have in that column?

Comment: Datatype of column is varchar(50)

Comment: I have edited the code, Can you try now? put your date column in place of '2017-08-25'.

Answer (score 0):

try with this query :

```
SELECT BNK_DATE, TO_CHAR(BNK_DATE, 'dd-MON-yyyy') FROM dim_today
```

in my case my table name in 'dim_today' and date column name BNK_DATE which data type is DATE.
this SQL work well in Oracle 11g

[image: my output is --]

Comment: TO_CHAR() is not recognized built in function name in SQL server 2012